# close() init() methods of stream Processor: Behaviour of Stream thread when rebalance happens?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to know the behaviour of `Kafka streams` (I am using low level Java API). I am implementing `Stream processor` by implementing interface `org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.Processor`.

`org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.Processor`  has following methods:

void init(ProcessorContext context);

void close();

Assuming kafka topic has 6 partitions and in my streaming application it has `num.stream.threads=1` and have `SIX instances of streaming application` running in different machines. So it would mean each stream thread will have ONLY ONE partition assigned.

Assuming one of the machines crashes and then we are left with five machines. Now, this will trigger a re-balance, when it happens , I have following questions:

- Does StreamThread die when a re-balance happens? As StreamThread is a thread, so during rebalancing do they remain "alive" or all Stream threads are "killed" and created again?
- Are init() / close()  called when creating StreamProcessor instance OR for each re-balancing OR when StreamThread is created? Basically want to know at what stage these methods are called and relationship w.r.t rebalance/ creation of stream thread / while a processor instance is created or when creating stream-tasks.
- How can I make client leave group programmatically?  I did search on this, however, getting irrelevant results.

Answer (score 3):

> Does StreamThread die when a re-balance happens? As StreamThread is a thread, so during rebalancing do they remain "alive" or all Stream threads are "killed" and created again?

No, the threads stays alive. (Only the thread from the crashed machine would obviously be dead.)

> Are init() / close() called when creating StreamProcessor instance OR for each re-balancing OR when StreamThread is created? Basically want to know at what stage these methods are called and relationship w.r.t rebalance/ creation of stream thread / while a processor instance is created or when creating stream-tasks.

It depends on the version. In older versions (2.3.x or older) during a rebalance, all tasks are suspended (ie, pause) to hence `close()` will be called. If an existing task is resumed (or migrated and thus re-create) `init()` is called. Hence, basically when a `StreamThread` is started, it first trigger a rebalance, and after partitions are assigned, tasks are created and corresponding `init()` calls are made. For existing `StreamThreads` when a rebalance is triggered, all tasks are suspended (ie, calls to `close()` are made) and re-assigned as well as new tasks are started again.

In newer versions (2.4.x and newer), an incremental rebalancing is done and thus tasks are not suspended during a rebalance any longer. Only when a task is migrated away from one `StreamThread` to another, the task would be closed on one thread and re-initialized on the new thread.

> How can I make client leave group programmatically? I did search on this, however, getting irrelevant results.

Not sure what you exactly mean. However, you can call `KafkaStreams#close()` to stop all its local `StreamThreads` and thus those threads would leave the group eventually.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This might be a stupid question, but can you explain how close() is called when tasks are suspended? I tried navigating through the code and couldn't find the link.

Comment: During a rebalance, a listener is called (look for `RebalanceListener` in `StreamThread` in `2.3`, or `StreamsRebalanceListener` in later versions) that calls `TaskManager#suspendTasksAndState()` that calls `active.closeAllRestoringTasks()` in `2.3`.

Comment: Thank you so much! But isn't it closing just the state store? I guess based on where you pointed, `active.suspend()` calling `closeTopology()` function will lead to closing StreamThreads. Am I getting it wrong?

Comment: Without double checking the code `closeTopology()` should trigger `Processor#close()` to be called for each processor. And yes, state stores will be closed, too. However the `StreamThreads` will just continue to run.

Comment: This is where my confusion is(if you say StreamThreads continue to run, even after close). Everytime a rebalance is occuring, my stream threads are "informed to shutdown"(close() called). I have a simple topology of input-topic -> state store -> output-topic. I have 1 partition topics, and just 1 Kafka Streams consumer, so just 1 active stream thread.

Comment: If the thread shuts down, it's not a regular rebalance, but something went wrong. -- Please inspect the logs for more details. For example, one reason why we would shut down during a rebalance is, if we cannot fetch the metadata from the broker cluster about source topics to create the required tasks.

Comment: Could you please check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65406598/kafka-streams-eos-mode-informed-to-shutdown? I don't see anything in the logs, its just like the moment a rebalance is triggered and tasks are suspended, the Stream Thread is informed to ShutDown.